# GWT/GAE Spring IoC powered

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm trying to put together Google App Engine and Google Web Toolkit for one of my projects.

I think I'm going to use Objectify for data persistence, too.

The guys of Springsource says that integrate those technology with Spring is possible.

Do you know where can I find some sort of tutorial about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any extra stuff required, no special configurations, tricks, etc. If you know both Spring and GAE - just use it, it's pretty standard.

I've few project based on Spring+GAE+Objectify+Java/Groovy - everything working fine together.

**update:**

Spring is good only for server-side part. As you want to use `IoC` on client side (in GWT part), you can use `Google GIN` instead. It's `Google Guice` framework (IoC from Google) designed for using with GWT.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/

Comment: I already knew that. I just wanted to see some code / configuration example, I'm a beginner...

Comment: what example do you want, exactly?

Comment: ehm.... Surely you know the Stockwatcher tutorial. Ok, done. Now I want to inject some object in the Stockwatcher class, I need Spring. How I add it to that project? I mean, importing the jars, configuring the ioc container. I know what to be done, not how. :((

Comment: Oh, you asking about GWT part, sorry, i've missed it (It though it's about GAE, because Spring is server-side framework by the nature). Probably there is not Spring for GWT. BTW, there GIN (Google Guice for GWT) that brings IoC to GWT, see - http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/

Answer (score 1):

Spring + GAE == slow start up for every instance.
You will face performance problems.
In my project I had to get get rid of Spring once we had everything implemented :(
I wont use Spring + gae anymore