# What web frameworks can be used successfully on Google app engine? What about Struts/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, struts2, web-frameworks

I'm interested in porting an existing application which was written using Spring/Struts2/Hibernate to GAE. I didn't read many successful stories about that so first of all I'm wondering if it is wise to use any of them there. I want to get rid of hibernate and to use the google data store instead since it's obvious hibernate is not a good choice on GAE. So my main questions refers to Struts2(webworks)/Spring. My app uses simple JSP pages, no other template mechanism.

My question refers to the following aspects:

- Currently each page has struts actions associated. Each request is taken by struts dispatcher an then it is dispatched to specific action class after which it invokes a specific jsp, according to the config file.
- Everything is instantiated by Spring(actions, factories, hibernate layers,...)
- The security is managed through a Spring Security(former acegi).

My first impression is that I should get rid of Spring because GAE should manage all the objects in order to work in a distributed environment. I have a few antagonistic thoughts regarding Struts. However, if I get rid of them ,I'm not sure if I should do it and in case I will, what to choose instead. Is GAE good enough to provide all the things I needed? I assume instantiation should be handled by GAE to have a truly sclalable solution. What about session management, security & user privileges? GAE provides good mechanism to manage them behind the scene or I should manually handle them like in a classic jsp solution? Will I end in having a huge web.xml?

Are there any frameworks that fits well in GAE and which can replace Spring/Struts? I would be interested to find out from someone who experienced those problems in GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of frameworks which are known to work or to have issues:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

In general Hibernate will not work, but you could potentially [use Java Persistence](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.html) instead. Struts should be OK, but Spring Security is [not fully compatible](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava#Spring_Security) while other Spring parts are fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Struts is generally a layer over standard Servlet API - so it should be running without many changes. Spring also is not a problem, in fact, on the web there are many blog entries about spring on GAE. Hibernate - yeah, better use JPA.

If you want to rewrite whole app, you can always go with GWT, even with Spring ( [GWT/GAE Spring IoC powered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650966/gwt-gae-spring-ioc-powered) )